# Solr statsCache implementation LRUStatsCache throws NullPointerException

Tags: solr

I have massive problems with the Solr [*statsCache*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests#Configuring+statsCache+implementation) feature. Here is the [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1632) in JIRA. I'm using one collection with two shards and a replication factor of two.

## [image]

In the `solrconfig.xml` I add the following statsCache implementation:

```
<statsCache class="org.apache.solr.search.stats.LRUStatsCache"/>
```

I must use the statsCache feature, because in the base shard are more documents as in the edit shard. But the score must be global.

When I query something which starts a score calculation I get **sometimes and not determinist** the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.search.stats.LRUStatsCache.getPerShardTermStats(LRUStatsCache.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.search.stats.ExactStatsCache.sendGlobalStats(ExactStatsCache.java:237)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.createMainQuery(QueryComponent.java:922)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.regularDistributedProcess(QueryComponent.java:713)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.distributedProcess(QueryComponent.java:666)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:305)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:450)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The request `q=*:*` works fine everytime. But `q=SomeTerm` results sometimes in the `NullPointerException`.

I tried all statsCache implementation.

It was not possible for me to detect the problem. Can somebody help me with this?

Please leave a comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared this question on Twitter with [@ApacheSolr](https://twitter.com/ApacheSolr). It's a bug which should be fixed in Solr 5.3 which should be released in the 1st week of August.

Here is the converstation:

> Solr statsCache implementation LRUStatsCache throws
>   NullPointerException http://t.co/dLT7aygoye /cc @ApacheSolr
>   ([Link](https://twitter.com/tim_krueger/status/622041913277968384))
>
> @tim_krueger we're aware of the bug. Should be fixed in the next
>   release 5.3. See https://t.co/kt7QredwKr
>   ([Link](https://twitter.com/ApacheSolr/status/622077200603308032))
>
> @ApacheSolr Thanks for the answer. Is there a known release date for
>   5.3?
>   ([Link](https://twitter.com/tim_krueger/status/622688906572636160))
>
> @tim_krueger can't say for sure but typically releases happen every
>   30-40 days so we can expect one around 1st week of August.
>   ([Link](https://twitter.com/ApacheSolr/status/623345853135085572))